# Android Service: onBind(Intent) and onUnbind(Intent) is called just once

Tags: android, binding, service

I have the Activity and the Service. When Activity is started, it calls `startService()` to make this Service be alive even when Activity is destroyed, and `bindService()`, to communicate with this Service.

`bindService()` returns true, `mService.onBind()` is called, and `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` is called too. All works.

When i destroy my Activity by pressing Back key, it calls `unbindService()`, and my `mService.onUnbind()` is called. (i return `false` in this `onUnbind()`.)

Then i start this Activity again, `bindService()` returns true, and then `mService.onBind()` is **NOT** called! But `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` is called too, and all works again.

It looks like Dalvik remembers what my `onBind()` returned last time, and just does not call `onBind()` again. When i destroy my Activity again, `onUnbind()` is **NOT** called too.

I can bind and unbind this Service to my Activity any number of times, but these methods will not be called anymore until I destroy Service by unbinding and calling `stopService()`.

In docs i can't find any explanation of this behavior. Conversely, [this figure](http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/service_binding_tree_lifecycle.png) shows that `onBind()` and `onUnbind()` should be called every time clients bind and unbind Service. This figure can be found on the bottom of [this Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Basics) (referenced from official dev guide) can explain all your queries:

> Multiple clients can connect to the service at once. However, the system calls your service's onBind() method to retrieve the IBinder only when the first client binds. The system then delivers the same IBinder to any additional clients that bind, without calling onBind() again.

Comment: oh thanks. I missed this, unfortunately. However, i found out that i can return true in `onUnbind()`, and then `onRebind()` and `onUnbind()` will be called for next client.

Comment: The documentation is actually misleading. It says that no more calls to `onBind()` are done, but this applies only to the case of multiple clients. Docs also say that "if your service is started and accepts binding, then when the system calls your onUnbind() method, you can optionally return true if you would like to receive a call to onRebind() the next time a client binds to the service (**instead of receiving a call to onBind()**)". Only there's no call to `onBind()`. Yet another case when documentation is wrong.

Comment: sorry for bumping in @Malcolm... i have a question regarding that Binding and unBinding stuff. WHat about if I put a ServerSocket Thread inside that Service, and in Activity-A i put onStart() and onStop() with binding and unbinding accordingly. Would it be recreated if I move to another activity and binding it again? or will the Thread still remain the last one?

Comment: @gumuruh Sorry for taking time to answer. According to [Android documentation on services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding), the service will not be recreated if you use `onStart` and `onStop` to do the binding and unbinding. Maybe you should open a separate question for this (if doesn't exist yet, of course).

Comment: Also important to note: `onBind()` is called multiple times in cases where clients send Intents with a different `action` while calling `bindService()`. Different `extras` doesn't seem to matter, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

You can connect multiple clients to a service simultaneously. However, the system caches the IBinder service communication channel. In other words, the system calls the service's onBind() method to generate the IBinder only when the first client binds. The system then delivers that same IBinder to all additional clients that bind to that same service, without calling onBind() again.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind all the clients, then the service will be destroyed, and then the `onBind` will be called, if this is what you want.