# Android - Keep app in focus with service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I've got an app for kids in which I want to prevent them accessing phone features. It doens't have to be rock-solid, just avoiding accidental exits.

The approach I am using is to start a service to monitor when my Activity goes out of focus, which then restarts it. I've followed the guide here:

http://nathanael.hevenet.com/android-dev-detecting-when-your-app-is-in-the-background-across-activities/

The idea is your activity binds to a service in onStart, and unbinds during onStop(). When the last activity unbinds, onUnbind gets called in the Service, from which I relaunch the Activity.

Heres the Activity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Next call always returns true
        bindService( new Intent( this, LockService.class ),
                mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService( mConnection );
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected( ComponentName cn, IBinder service ) {}
        public void onServiceDisconnected( ComponentName cn ) {}
    };
}
```

And here's the Service:

```
public class LockService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        refocus();
    }

    private void refocus() {
        // Launch the monitored Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GameActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind( Intent intent ) {
        // Relaunch
        refocus();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LockService getService() {
            return LockService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
}
```

This works but only once. When the GameActivity is closed or minimised, the LockService.onUnbind gets called.

This relaunches the GameActivity, which tries to bind to the service again. It returns true, but LockService.onBind does not happen a second time, and consequently LockService.onUnbind doesn't happen when the Activity stops. The link is lost.

Now, I have DEFINITELY had this working but I've changed something and broken it. Perhaps the way I am relaunching the Activity? I wish I'd checked it into SVN when it worked!

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

EDIT: Here's how I start the service, from MenuActivity:

```
public static void StartLockService() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LockService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: how do you start the service initially?

Comment: @Libin I've included how I start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it, thanks to [Android Service: onBind(Intent) and onUnbind(Intent) is called just once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788103/android-service-onbindintent-and-onunbindintent-is-called-just-once)

Looks like I needed to return true from onUnbind to indicate I wanted onRebind notifications.

Then I can refocus my app in onRebind.