# Issues when trying to bind to a service after unbinding

Tags: android, service

I've created a simple class which extends the Service class to understand how services work. But I've got a problem. I want my service to run without interruption while I'm binding and unbinding. I start the service inside activity, then I bind the activity to it, unbind and bind again. But the things after the unbinding does not go well. I don't get the output of `onBind(Intent intent)` and `onUnbind(Intent intent)` or `onRebind(Intent intent)` methods in the service.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MyActivity.log("service created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MyActivity.log("service started");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        MyActivity.log("service destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        MyActivity.log("binded");
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        MyActivity.log("unbinded");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        MyActivity.log("rebinded");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788103/android-service-onbindintent-and-onunbindintent-is-called-just-once

Comment: post the client's code

Comment: Please post your activity code as well